# A way to distinguish the scintillation light from the Cherenkov radiation

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, particle-detectors, cherenkov-radiation

I am using a scintillator-PMT ov scintillator-SiPM system.
When I obtain signals from the system, I will get both scintillation photons and Cherenkov radiation in my DAQ. Is there a way to distinguish which is the scintillation signal and which is the Cherenkov radiation signal in the whole data?

I want to know how much the scintillation event happens, and how much the Cherenkov event happens.

Answer (score 1):

In an actual setup, you will have little to go by other than the timing structure of your signals. Expect the Cerenkov flash to come fast, whereas the scintillation follows the particular time constants of your scintillator. Scintillators often follow one rise time and two decay times. You can get those numbers from the literature for your scintillator, fit them to a given pulse, and a fast excess on top of that is likely due to Cerenkov radiation.

Alternatively, if you were to have high energy signals and a pixelated readout, then scintillation would be uniform/isotropic, whereas Cerenkov radiation would be emitted in its characteristic cone, leaving a ring of light on your readout plane.

Comment: Thank you so much! That would be a perfect way to distinguish those!